# Starting one thread at the end of another

Tags: android

I have an application in which i have 3-4 threads , i want that 2nd thread must start when 1st thread ends , 3rd when 2nd ends and so on.. I am giving the code..

```
//1st thread

new Thread(new Runnable() {


                int progressStatus = 0;

                public void run() {

                        progressStatus = dofirstWork();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Update the progress bar
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                bar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                            }
                        });

                }
                private int dofirstWork() {


                    //do some work
                    return 25;

                 }

                }).start();         
                    //2nd thread

new Thread(new Runnable() {


                int progressStatus = 0;

                public void run() {

                        progressStatus = dosecondWork();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Update the progress bar
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                bar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                            }
                        });

                }
                private int dosecondWork() {


                    //do some work
                    return 50;

                 }

                }).start();   

                    //3rd thread

new Thread(new Runnable() {


                int progressStatus = 0;

                public void run() {

                        progressStatus = dothirdWork();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Update the progress bar
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                bar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                            }
                        });

                }
                private int dothirdWork() {


                    //do some work
                    return 75;

                 }

                }).start();
```

Actually , i m trying to display progress bar at 25% for 1st function call, at 50 % for second operation and so .. on.. plz help

Comment: If you're running them in sequence instead of at the same time, you don't need multiple threads. Just have one thread that calls each work routine when the previous one is finished.

Comment: u mean i should call the functions doFirstwork() , doSecondWork(),Dowthirdwork() sequentially in one thread only??

Comment: Yes. If you're running one thread, waiting for it to finish, starting another, and so forth, there's no advantage of having more than 1 thread. Using multiple threads is so they can all run *at the same time*; if you're running them sequentially, you're adding a lot of wasted overhead for no benefit.

Comment: Think of moving furniture. You have 4 pieces of furniture to move, and 4 people. Is it better to have Person1 move 1 chair, while the other 3 wait, and then have Person2 move 1 chair while Persons 3 & 4 wait, etc., or is it better to have all 4 people each moving a chair at the same time? If they're moving one piece  at a time, the other 3 people could just stay home.

Comment: @ken white .. i am getting a logcat error  java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 1):

```
    package com.integrated.mpr;

import org.apache.commons.math.linear.RealMatrix;
import org.apache.commons.math.stat.correlation.Covariance;
import org.apache.commons.math.stat.correlation.PearsonsCorrelation;
import org.apache.commons.math.util.FastMath;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Logic extends Activity{

    int n = Choose.n;
    double final_matrix[][] = new double[n][5];
    double swap =0;

    double weightage_matrix[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    double sorted_weightage[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    String  display[] = new String[n]; 

    double input_matrix[][] = new double[22050][n];
    double[] peak_matrix = new double[n];
    double[] sd_matrix = new double[n];
    double[] rms_matrix = new double[n];
    double[] cf_matrix = new double[n];
    double[] mean_matrix = new double[n];
    int[] sensitive_positions = new int[n];
    double[] new_sensitive = new double[n];
    int[] sortsensi = new int[n];


    private static final int Progress = 0;

    ProgressBar bar;
    TextView label;
    Handler handler = new Handler();




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress);

        bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progBar);

        final Handler handler=new Handler()
        {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {


                 int what=msg.what;
                 switch(what)
                 { 
                    case 1:
                          {
                            //do some long operation
                          }


                    case 2:

                    {
                        //do some long operation
                    }
                          break;

                    case 3:

                    {
                    // do some long operation
                    }

                    break;

                    case 4 :

                    {
                        //do some long opeartion


                    }
                        break;

                 }
            }
        };




            new Thread(new Runnable() {



                int progressStatus = 0;

                public void run() {


                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                bar.setProgress(25);

                            }
                        });
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                bar.setProgress(50);

                            }
                        });
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(3);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                bar.setProgress(75);

                            }
                        });
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(4);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                bar.setProgress(100);

                            }
                        });
                        // Update the progress bar


                }

            }).start();         


            Intent openList=new Intent("com.integrated.mpr.SENSITIVELIST");
            startActivity(openList);

        }
```

Comment: hi i have added the codes over there it is too simple .... use this if you are not satisfied i will give another way of updating the status.

Comment: sorry for get to mention the link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/

Comment: @Rajesh .. i am getting a logcat error java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(

Comment: hi ... I think u are calling some mothod inside the runnable thread.. you should use the "Handler" to call that method... below is the developers link for how to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: private Handler handlerStart = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
   new Task().execute();                                                                                                             

  }
 };   you should call this handler like this  handlerStart.sendEmptyMessage(0);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12051/discussion-between-kumar-and-rajesh)